# Bootstrap's event handler not working in Emberjs component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

In my component's didInsertElement() method I register event handler for Bootstraps's tab component:

```
didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    console.log('didInsertElement....');
    console.log(this.$("a[data-toggle='tab']"));

    this.$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
        console.log('TAB SHOWN....');
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

However, my handler is not executed. I copied the same handler code on console in browser and it works. This only seems to be in case of Bootsrap tab. Appearance of my console messages confirm that didInsertElement() is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a checklist to try:

1. Tabs need to be activated individually, according to [the docs for bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs). I don't see anything in your code samples showing that the tabs have been activated with a `click` handler.
2. Handlers will only attach to elements that already exist in the DOM at the time of didInsertElement, so if tabs matching that selector are revealed by another action (like opening a modal), they won't work. Add a debug statement to inspect the DOM at the time of didInsertElement and look for the things you are trying to select.
3. Do `$('#someTab').tab('show')` just before and after you register the handler to see if anything happens
4. Are you missing an `e.preventDefault()` somewhere, like on a click handler? Since tabs are anchor tags, there's some weird behavior sometimes.

I strongly recommend using [ember-bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) over regular Bootstrap. JQuery listeners slow your app down, and making modifications to the DOM directly will fail under edge conditions or cause other parts of your app to break in unexpected ways.

*This answer applies from at least versions 1.13 and was written as of 3.1*